# Android: How to start new activity for OnItemClick of List View that uses content provider

Tags: android, android-intent

By using the content provider I have inflated SMS in Inbox List View of my application. Now On item Click I want to show SMS text in another activity. I've implemented custom list view. Now I am not getting how to pick each single list item and show in new activity on click. In a Stack flow answer somebody suggested this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Uri mailUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(getIntent().getData(), id);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mailUri));
}
```

If this code is correct then how I will configure next activity to act upon this ACTION_VIEW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
        Intent i= new Intent(currentClass.this,secondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("string",Yourlist.get(pos).sms);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();                       
    }
});
```

& on Another Activity You can receive through this:-

```
String msg=getIntent().getExtras().getString("string");
```

Comment: Here it shows error for @override annotation. Also in following line of code: i.putExtra("string",Yourlist.get(pos).sms); It shows error for '.sms'. My list is declared like this:  List<InboxItem> inboxItems = getSMS(); So my line of code was: i.putExtra("string",inboxItems.get(pos).sms);. On receiving activity it shows error for getExtra and suggest to make it getExtras. Any idea of the problem?

Comment: yes it should be getExtras() & Show InboxItems .according your InboxItems if u use setter getter then it should be something like this:- i.putExtra("string",inboxItems.get(pos).getSms());

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)  {   
switch(position)
{ case 0:
Intent firstIntent = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);
startActivity(firstIntent);
break;
case 1:
Intent secondintent = new Intent(AndroidListViewActivity.this,jokes.class);               
startActivity(secondintent);
break;
```